# How can I see the size of a single slice?

Tags: photoshop

In Photoshop, how can I view the size (width x height) of a slice? I use Photoshop CS6.

Comment: If you're editing slices and can click to select one, try going to View > Toolbars and see if there's a 'Slices' panel that you can display, that should show the properties of the selected slice. What version of Photoshop are you using?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Photoshop for... Web design or something. Not photography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves, you can right-click on the slice and choose Properties, where the width and height are displayed.

Comment: In my version, this is called slice properties.